# how to check duplicate values in multiple array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple array. I want check duplicate data. If there duplicate values, I want ignore it and go to the another value. I wrote code. but, that is not working properly. please help me.

**This is my array**

```
    Array([1] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200301
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => maths
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_1
               [MARKS] => 25 )
  [2] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200301
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => maths
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_2
               [MARKS] => 45 )
  [3] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200301
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => art
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_1
               [MARKS] => 76 )
  [4] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200301
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => art
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_2
               [MARKS] => 42 )
  [5] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200302
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => maths
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_1
               [MARKS] => 71 )
  [6] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200302
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => maths
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_2
               [MARKS] => 78 )
  [7] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200302
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => art
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_1
               [MARKS] => 35 )
  [8] => Array([STUDENT_ID] => 200302
               [SUBJECT_NAME] => art
               [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => exam_2
               [MARKS] => 61 )
 )
```

**I wrote PHP code**

```
foreach($result as $item => &$rv) {

if($item == 0) {
    $subjectName = $rv[SUBJECT_NAME];
    echo '***'.$rv[SUBJECT_NAME];
}
if(strcmp($rv[SUBJECT_NAME] === $subjectName)) {
    continue; 
    }else {

    $subjectName = $rv[SUBJECT_NAME];
    echo '---'. $rv[SUBJECT_NAME];
}
}
```

**I want create like this table**

```
|-------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       |            |     maths       |      art        |  
|Seq No | Student Id |-----------------|-----------------|
|       |            | Exam 1 | Exam 2 | Exam 1 | Exam 2 |
|-------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1    | 200301     |   25   |   45   |  76    |  42    |
|  2    | 200302     |   71   |   78   |  35    |  61    |
|-------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
```

Comment: Can you exactly define what constitutes 'duplicate data'?

Comment: So you want unique subject from array?

Comment: @B.Desai, yes i want unique subject from array.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I'm getting this data in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can store subject wise value in temp array then check that array

```
<?php
$tmp_results = array();
foreach($result as $item => &$rv) {
    if(!isset($tmp_results[$rv['SUBJECT_NAME']]))
    {
        echo '***'.$rv['SUBJECT_NAME'];
        $tmp_results[$rv['SUBJECT_NAME']] = $rv;
    }
}
//Also now $tmp_results contains only uniques subjetcs
print_r($tmp_results);
```

Comment: Please can you check my table. actually i want create like that table.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code is that you want an array with all the subjects in the source array. You can do this with two simple PHP array function:

```
$subjects = array_unique(array_column($result,'SUBJECT_NAME'));
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

And: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: your `array_unique` function is ok. But, I have more than 100 subjects and more than 1000 `student_ID`. There fore i want check array one by one. there fore I want write `foreach`.